# How do I remove the overlap from merged meshes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, knife-tool

I have recently decided to delve back into 3D modeling, I am a hobbyist I guess you could say.  I have been trying to find a solution for this particular problem for days now.  I have scoured this as well as other forums and have yet to find an answer to this dilemma.  This is my first post here so I hope I don't make too much of a fool of myself :P

I am currently trying to merge three rectangular cubes to form a symbol:
[image]

The problem arises when I goto render the picture:
[image]

I have tried Joining the objects then going back with the Knife and removing doubles, which seems to be the answer to this, but I keep getting the overlap.

I am sure it is a simple fix but I have probably burned myself out on finding it.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

If I have managed to miss another answer to this in my search could you please link it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with the **TinyCAD** addon or with some **extrudes**.

If you want to start with your 3 parallelepipeds you could use the **TinyCAD addon**:

- [Download](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/mesh_tinyCAD) and istall the addon.
- Join your parallelepipeds with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, and go in *Edit* mode.
- Select all and press <kbd>W</kbd> > TinyCAD > XALL.
- Keep everything selected and press <kbd>W</kbd> > Remove Doubles.
- Delete the inner vertices so that you won't have any inner edges in the final object.
- Fill all the faces.

[image]

If you want to do it with some **extrudes**, you could:

- Start with a plane, create an edge loop on its middle and tilt it with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.
- Bevel the middle edge loop with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and create 2 new edge loops.
- Extrude the plane.
- Select a face and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>spacebar</kbd> to create a new custom *Transformation Orientation* (named "Face.001" by default).
- Keep this new orientation selected.
- Select one of the faces you need to extrude, press <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away.
- Move this new face along the *Face.001* Y axis.
- Same thing for the other face.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this.  After a bit of fumbling around with it I figured out I had to Join the parallelepipeds prior to switching to Edit Mode for the rest of the steps mentioned above.  This was, I am sure, one of many hurdles in my self-assigned project and it is nice to have a place to go for advice.

Comment: oh ok I thought you'd know you would have to join   ;)

Comment: I am learning/relearning this world, again, after a few years.  I am mainly doing it for fun but you never know where it can go.  I am mainly using projects to learn more about the program. If there are any tutorials or informational material you would recommend that would be cool.  I have googled about 100 tutorials and courses but just use them as needed.

Comment: hard to say, at the beginning I followed a lot of random tutorials that seem interesting, then a thing that helps a lot is to have my own project, for example create a fake animation movie trailer, which forced me to solve the problems I came across, like make a character walk, a camera follow a path, etc... I think it's the best way to learn: cope with problems to solve  ;)